# Copy and Pasting Columns through Arrays

Tags: excel, vba

Copy and pasting the columns `A2:A` and `B2:A` from `Sheet1` to `Sheet6` and my code is working fine.

when code paste the data it starts pasting form `A1` and `B1` i want to paste the data form `A2` and `B2` in Sheet6.

```
Dim ColumnAarray() As Variant
Dim my_Arange As Range
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set my_Arange = Sheet1.Range("A2:B" & LastRow)
ReDim ColumnAarray(LastRow)
ColumnAarray = my_Arange
For i = LBound(ColumnAarray) To UBound(ColumnAarray)
    Sheet6.Range("A" & i) = ColumnAarray(i, 1)
    Sheet6.Range("B" & i) = ColumnAarray(i, 2)
Next i
```

I just want to paste the data from row2.

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Be specific please.

Comment: I updated my question. with pictures

Comment: Please include a complete description of what your code should actually do. Because with that loop your code is very inefficient and I think you are already up the wrong tree. So you need to go one step back to get it solved. Please tell what you actually want to do with that code. Because if it is *"Copy and pasting the columns A2:A and B2:A from Sheet1 to Sheet6"* that is perfectly covered by my answer below.

Comment: Sorry we don't download files from unkonwn sources. If you want to explain something put everything you need into the question itself. Files may disappear after a while and the question gets useless for future readers. So according [ask] everyhing to understand your question has to be in the question itself. • Note that copying that data in a loop is horrendously slow and therefore does not make any sense. So please explain why there has to be that loop. I mean you don't run 3 times around your house to get in if you can get in straight forward.

Comment: Understand thanks `Note that copying that data in a loop is horrendously slow and therefore does not make any sense.` your this point clarifies great. i was unable to get your point earlier apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop to do that

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim ColumnAarray() As Variant
ColumnAarray = Sheet1.Range("A2:B" & LastRow).Value
Sheet6.Range("A2:B" & LastRow).Value = ColumnAarray
```

Actually you don't even need an array

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Sheet6.Range("A2:B" & LastRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("A2:B" & LastRow).Value
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i need to fix this through loop and Arrays. I hope you would understand. Thanks

Comment: @Valiant No I don't understand why you need that. Please edit your original question and make clear why. Because for the example you show that is not necessary. Your question is very unclear then, please clarify.

Comment: Let me do this.

Comment: `Your this code is working fine i want my arrays code to work like this`

Comment: *"I want"* is not an explanation I can understand. It is like you are running around your house 3 times while you can just get in straight forward. Why would you want to have your code horrendously slow if you can have the same fast?