# Filter and Copy Paste Values using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67417298/copy-and-pasting-columns-through-arrays).

I am trying to extract the Col"A" values between two dates. I got the solution via Excel formula. I wasn't aware that with large data a formula will take much time.

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,A:A*(B:B>=$F$2)*(B:B<=$G$2),ROW(A1))
```

I tried with VBA that If Col"B" Dates are `=>` between two dates `<=` then copy Col"A" values and paste.

```vb
Dim s1 As Worksheet
Dim s3 As Worksheet
Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set s3 = Sheets("Sheet3")
Set s4 = Sheets("Sheet4")
Dim i As Long, lr As Long, lr3 As Long
lr = s1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim Dstart As Date
Dim Dend As Date
Dstart = s4.Range("M10").Value
Dend = s4.Range("N10").Value

For i = 2 To lr
    If s1.Range("B" & i) >= Dstart And .Range("B" & i) <= Dend Then
        s1.Range("A" & i).Copy
        s3.Range("X3:X" & i).Paste xlValues
    End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would strongly benefit from learning to use arrays when working in VBA as working in memory will make your scripts exponentially faster.

To get you on track this should help you to figure it out:

```
    Option Explicit 'always add this
    
    Sub test()
        Dim arr, arr2, j As Long, i As Long, Dstart As Date, Dend As Date
        
        arr = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value 'get the dates in memory
        Dstart = Sheet1.Range("c1").Value
        Dend = Sheet1.Range("c2").Value
        ReDim arr2(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1) 'setup temp array
        i = 1 'don't like to start at 0
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr) 'traverse source dates
            If arr(j, 1) >= Dstart And arr(j, 1) <= Dend Then 'check if date is in range
                arr2(i, 1) = arr(j, 1) 'store matching dates in temp array
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next j
        
        With Sheet2
            .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(arr2), 1)).Value = arr2 'paste to sheet
        End With
    End Sub
```

notes:

- Dates to copy are in colA
- start endate are in colC
- matching results are paste in sheet2

don't hesitate if you have questions to adapt this to your specific setup.